# R shiny: how to create a matrix with numericInput as elements

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a matrix in which one could insert numeric values. Also, I would like that the number of rows visible depend on an actionButton. The following code herebelow works fine as long as I've got NAs in my matrix, but not if I replace the NA by some numericInput.

Here is the ui.R:

```
shinyUI(
pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("test"),
sidebarPanel(
actionButtonGreen("test","add a row")),
mainPanel(
uiOutput("value"))
)
)
```

And here is the server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){

observe({
if (input$test == 0) 
return()
isolate({ 
output$value <-renderTable( 
mdat <- matrix(NA, nrow = input$test, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) 
)
##If I change the NAs to a vector of numericInput, I obtain the following error
##Error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length 
##That's when I replace the NA in the above matrix with
##c(numericInput(inputId="1",label="",value="2"),
##  numericInput(inputId="2",label="",value="2"),
##  numericInput(inputId="3",label="",value="2"), 
##  numericInput(inputId="4",label="",value="2"))                    
})})
```

}
  )

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are trying to insert into your matrix (the value of `numericInput(inputId="1",label="",value="2")`) :

```
[1] "<label for=\"1\"></label>\n<input id=\"1\" type=\"number\" value=\"2\"/>"
attr(,"html")
[1] TRUE
```

and this is his structure, it's a list of 2 lists with 3 elements :

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ name    : chr "label"
  ..$ attribs :List of 1
  .. ..$ for: chr "1"
  ..$ children:List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr ""
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ name    : chr "input"
  ..$ attribs :List of 3
  .. ..$ id   : chr "1"
  .. ..$ type : chr "number"
  .. ..$ value: chr "2"
  ..$ children: list()
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "shiny.tag.list" "list"
```

Your problem is that the function `numericInput` returns something that cant fit into you matrix.

Then I suggest you to use directly the html tag in a data frame, and with the `sanitize.text.function` function to evaluate the HTML tags as is (and not as strings).

```
shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel("test"),
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("test","add a row")),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("value"))
  ),   
  server = function(input,output){
    observe({
      if (input$test == 0) 
        return()
      isolate({
        output$value <-renderTable({
          num.inputs.col1 <- paste0("<input id='c1n", 1:input$test, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='2'>")
          num.inputs.col2 <- paste0("<input id='c2n", 1:input$test, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='2'>")
          data.frame(num.inputs.col1, num.inputs.col2)
        }, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
      })
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: This is brilliant: This works perfectly. Many thanks. But now comes the bonus question: how can I extract the value of the first cell of the matrix ? I have tried to insert output$c <-renderUI(h4(input$c11)) in the server and uiOutput("c") in the ui, but it does not recognize it. Any idea why ? (many thanks for all your answers so far, very very much appreciated)

Comment: Normaly you can access them this way, but I think you didn't notice the "n" in my id. Try with `input$c1n1` instead of `input$c11`, it should works :)

Comment: Yes indeed ! it's a very elegant solution. Many thanks

Comment: Hi Julien, just a quick question if you don't mind: where can I find a comprehensive documentation of all classes ? I see that you use shiny-bound-input, but I don't really know what it means and what other shiny classes are available ? (I tried to google it but without success). Thanks in advance

Comment: No sorry I don't know where you can find this doc. I just inspected the source code of a shiny app an got the class of the `numericInput` element.

Comment: Good job! just another question: Is it possible to store the data that the user enter to the matrix? How?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote these functions to do the same thing. Hope this helps.

```
 columm    <- function(x,checkval) { if (is.na(checkval)) {
                                                      return(paste('<td>',x,'</td>', sep=""))
                                                      } else {
                                                      return(paste('<td style="background-color:lightblue;">',x,'</td>', sep=""))
                                                      }
                            }
num_input <- function(id,checkval,default){  if (!is.na(checkval)) {
                                                      return(default) 
                                                      } else { 
                                                      return(paste("<input id='",id,"' type='number' value=",default, 
                                                             " class='myInputstyle'>",sep="")) 
                                                      }
  }
```