# R Shiny: matrix with numericInputs

Tags: r, matrix, shiny

My question relates to question already asked here: [R shiny: how to create a matrix with numericInput as elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119938/r-shiny-how-to-create-a-matrix-with-numericinput-as-elements/26722184#26722184). Ive used the proposed solution there, but it does not fully solve my problem.

Please have a look at my code and help me with the following issues.

The idea is to create an app where user enters some a-priori information into table/matrix. The number of rows can be different, depending on a number of analysed groups, and elements of the matrix are numerical and positive only. Now:

1) I can add the rows, but cannot decrease their number. Some relevant actionButton might be useful.

2) I would like to carry out some calculation on the resulting table/matrix columns, but not on individual elements (input$c1n1, input$c1n2 ...).

3) The sum of the first column elements is calculated as the elements are entered. I would like to do it when the matrix is ready by clicking a button ('Calculate 1st column sum').

Your help is much appreciated. Robert

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
observe({

    if (input $ new.group == 0)
        return()else{
    isolate({
        output $ table <- renderTable({
            numImp1 <- paste0("<input id='c1n", 1:input $ new.group, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='' min='0' step=.01>")
            numImp2 <- paste0("<input id='c2n", 1:input $ new.group, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='' min='0' step=.01>")
            table = data.frame(Value1 = numImp1, Value2 = numImp2)
    rownames(table) = paste('Group',1:nrow(table), sep='')
    table
        }, sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})


        output $ Sum.V1 <-  renderPrint({
            sum.V1 <- sum(input $ c1n1, input $ c1n2, input $ c1n3, input $ c1n4, input $ c1n5, input $ c1n6, input $ c1n7, input $ c1n8, na.rm=T)
            return(sum.V1)
        })
    })}
})
```

})

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel(""),
sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("new.group", "Add group"),
    actionButton("calc.sum", "Calculate 1st column sum")
    ),
mainPanel(
    h3('Table'),
    tableOutput("table"),
    h3('Resulting sum of the first column'),
    verbatimTextOutput('Sum.V1')
    )
)
```

)