# How to extract input from a dynamic matrix in R shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

This is related to an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119938/r-shiny-how-to-create-a-matrix-with-numericinput-as-elements?answertab=active#tab-top) about creating a matrix-style input in a shiny app with dynamic dimensions.  My goal is to have a matrix of numerical inputs (the dimensions of which are determined by other user inputs), and then pass that matrix to other R commands and print some output from those calculations.  I have code that successfully executes everything except that I can only access the user inputs as characters.

Here is an example that sets up the input and just prints a couple cells from the matrix (this works fine, but isn't what I need):

```
shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("test"),
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "nrow",
                   label = "number of rows",
                   min = 1,
                   max = 20,
                   value = 1),
      numericInput(inputId = "ncol",
                   label = "number of columns",
                   min = 1,
                   max = 20,
                   value = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("value"),
      uiOutput("textoutput"))
  ),   

  server = function(input,output){
    isolate({
      output$value <-renderTable({
        num.inputs.col1 <- paste0("<input id='r", 1:input$nrow, "c", 1, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='1'>")
        df <- data.frame(num.inputs.col1)
        if (input$ncol >= 2){
          for (i in 2:input$ncol){
            num.inputs.coli <- paste0("<input id='r", 1:input$nrow, "c", i, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='1'>")
            df <- cbind(df,num.inputs.coli)
          }
        }

        colnames(df) <- paste0("time ",as.numeric(1:input$ncol))
        df
      }, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
    })
    output$textoutput <- renderUI(paste0("Cells [1,1] and [2,2]: ",input$r1c1,",",input$r2c2))
  }
))
```

However, when I try to do any operation on the inputs in the matrix, such as `output$textoutput <- renderUI(as.numeric(paste0(input$r1c1))+as.numeric(paste0(input$r2c2)))`, I get classic R errors like `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.  I have tried many combinations of 'as.numeric', 'as.character', ect. to try to get it into the correct format.  When I check the structure of those input cells, I see that they have an extra 'NULL' attribute that I can't seem to get rid of, but I am unsure if that is the root of the problem.

In short, how do I extract the plain numbers from that matrix? Or is there a better way to do this in shiny?  The only other solution I'm aware of is the rhandsontable package, which I would prefer not to use if there is a reasonable alternative.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.  Thank you!

Edit/solution: replacing `renderUI` and `uiOutput` with `renderPrint` and `verbatimTextOutput` solves the problem.  Thank you for the comment, blondeclover!

Comment: It's hard to help when variables you are referencing (e.g., `input$r1c1`) are not defined. However, I do know that using a grand `isolate` is absolutely breaking any semblance of reactivity you'll have ... though I can't imagine it would work (I'm not testing it now), I can't imagine things behaving well even if something in it did work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  With regards to the variable names, those come from the html labels (the `paste0` statements inside `renderTable`); my understanding is that each cell needs a unique label, so r1c1 is my shorthand for 'row 1 column 1', and so on.  With regards to the `isolate`, the same issues happen without it, but I will definitely go do some more reading on that.

Comment: If it isn't identified as an `id="..."` in the `ui` component of a shiny app (or within a dynamic-ui type thing), then you won't see it as `input$...`. Are you following a shiny tutorial?

Comment: I was basing this off of Julien Navarre's solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119938/r-shiny-how-to-create-a-matrix-with-numericinput-as-elements?answertab=active#tab-top) since I couldn't find any full tutorials that addressed my need to make a matrix.  I can access the cells using `input$...` (the example I made demonstrates selecting and printing a few cells), but I can't figure out how to force them to be numeric (i.e. printing the sum of two cells).

Comment: The inputs are numeric for me. I think your error comes from using `renderUI`. Try using `output$textoutput <- renderPrint({class(input$r1c1)})` on the server and `verbatimTextOutput("textoutput")` on the ui

Comment: blondeclover, I made those changes and it works perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @FoolOnTheHill happy to help! glad it's working for you